# AS3 - How to use child classes, how to create an instance of a child class?

Tags: actionscript-3

Very new to the forum, and AS3, but help would be much appreciated.
Not sure if i'm using all the right terms, but how do you create an instance of a child class?
This is what I have so far:

I have a 'mob_troll' movieclip with Class: troll and Base Class: [blank]

Main.as:

```
import mob

var troll:mob = new troll();
troll.Speed = 10
troll.Hp =10
```

troll.as:

```
package  { 
    import mob

    public class troll extends mob {

        public function troll(){
            trace('I work')
        }
    }
}
```

mob.as:

```
package  {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;  
    public class mob extends MovieClip {

        public var Speed:int;
        public var Hp:int;

        public function mob() {
            trace('mob')
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: see this answer - just addChild(); ! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12527079/flashdevelop-as3-project-adding-child-from-other-class-not-visible-keyboard-in?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I apologize if I'm stating the obvious but I wanted to make sure we understood each others terms.

Child classes (also known as sub classes or derived classes) are exactly what you've created with the line

```
public class Troll extends Mob { ... }
```

The class Troll is a child class of Mob. 
An instance is an occurrence of the class. which you have created with this line:

```
var troll:Mob = new Troll();
```

Specifically the part `new Troll()` creates the Troll instance. Then it is set to a variable which references a Mob.

So in this example you have already created a child class (the troll).

If you're wondering about how to see your movieclip visually on the stage, then you should read up on the AS3 Display list [here's a good starting point](http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3displaylist/). But essentially it would involve adding that instance to the stage. Assuming Main.as is your document class it would look something like this:

```
import Mob;
import Troll;

var troll:Mob = new Troll();
troll.Speed = 10
troll.Hp =10

this.addChild(troll);
```

Notice the import of Troll (you will need to import every type used)

Comment: Thanks for this, using 'troll' as the variable name (troll:mob = new troll():), throws an error I needed to use something else.

Comment: Good point, there is a naming conflict and the troll instance and the class have the same name. Sorry about that, should have compiled it before answering. One thing to note, in AS3 its convention to capitalize the class names. public class Troll extends Mob { ... } for example. Also variables are normally lower case, e.g. troll.speed = 10; troll.hp = 10; Following these conventions would avoid this naming conflict.